# Function returns invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.5, valueerror

I have a function, that parses string and takes values by using indexes. When I try to take the exact variable and convert it into integer, it gives me a ValueError. The exact code part is:

```
y = special_string[y_start:y_end]
print(y)
y = int(y)
```

Traceback for it:

```
14

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "levelBuilder.py", line 255, in <module>
    newLevel, rows, columns = importLevel(levelName)
  File "levelBuilder.py", line 124, in importLevel
    y = int(y)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The question is - what can cause this error? As you see, y is integer (14). When I use the same method for another variable (x), it works correctly

Comment: Need more info. Do `print(repr(y))` instead.

Comment: It shows the literal in the error message, it is an empty string.  It suggests that the `14` comes from somewhere else (note the blank line after it).  Suggest that you add more text to your `print` to identify it.

Comment: @cdarke, if you're not Kira Vergil using a different name, you're guessing about that.  My reason for asking is different than you seem to believe ;-)  But, yes, adding more text would also help.

Comment: @TimPeters:  I'm just reading the error messages, which says `y` is empty.  Its a comment and not an answer.  We don't see the whole program so can't see where the 14 or the slice is coming from.  Your suggestion to try `repr` is a good one, no point in me repeating it.

Comment: Thanks, understood. It seems to be that it throws the previous variable. Sorry for a silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 14
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "levelBuilder.py", line 255,
>   in 
>       newLevel, rows, columns = importLevel(levelName)

It looks like there is a space line between the "exception message" and "14". 
So, the y is ' ' , print(y) will print space line. int(y) will raise value err.
Maybe be you should remove the '*pyc' file and retry :-)